# Arabic characters doesn't show properly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

When I add a Arabic characters in JavaScript, It does not showed properly. I guess that is an ASCII problem. Any suggestions?

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('div-msg').innerText = "اسم المستخدم لا يمكن أن تترك فارغة";
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="div-msg" style="width:100%; height:200px; background:yellow">

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('div-msg').innerText = "اسم المستخدم لا يمكن أن تترك فارغة";
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: looks like it's working fine (at least for me, on Firefox) https://jsfiddle.net/6udL3oLh/1/

Comment: could you show an image how is it displayed ?
and the sentence is wrong it should be 
اسم المستخدم لا يمكن ان يترك فارغ

Comment: Did you save your file as UTF-8?  Does the servers response encoding match?

Comment: Thanks @YamenImadNassif :)

Comment: @AlexK. I just saved this code. And not working fine

Comment: What exactly does "not working fine" mean?!

Comment: The real root of the problem is: 1) What's your HTML file's encoding? How are you saving it in your text editor? 2) What does your *web server* declare your file's encoding to be? What `Content-Type` HTTP header is it served with? – There's a discrepancy there that you need to fix, that's all.

Comment: @deceze not working file means chars does not display properly.

Comment: So how *do* they display?

Comment: Like this. Ø§Ø³Ù… Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø³ØªØ®Ø¯Ù… Ù„Ø§ ÙŠÙ…ÙƒÙ† Ø£Ù† ØªØªØ±Ùƒ ÙØ§Ø±ØºØ©

Comment: Then the problem is that your web server is advertising your page as being encoding in ISO-8859-1 (or such) and/or that you have no encoding declaration at all in both your HTTP headers and HTML head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have already met with this issue when I tried to write Turkish characters. Solution is simple.

- First, move your JavaScript code to external script file.
- Second, add your script into HTML with charset attribute like below

  ```
  <script src="external_script.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
  ```

Comment: There's no need to move the code into an external file; it'll work just fine inline **if encodings are handled correctly.**

Comment: Yes it's working fine. Thank you. By the way, why shuld I move my JS codes to external file?

Comment: You are welcome @KhanImran. Because in the head tag, you did not specify the meta tag with charset attribute like <meta charset="UTF-8" />. If you don't want to move your code, add meta tag to in your HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that without moving your Javascript code to an external script file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar-AR" dir="RTL">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div-msg" style="width:100%; height:200px; background:yellow">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('div-msg').innerText = "اسم المستخدم لا يمكن أن تترك فارغة";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```