# UTF-8 Arabic in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38831465/arabic-characters-doesnt-show-properly-in-javascript), but it did not solve my issue, and as it is old, I'm posting a new question.

I've the below code, that is recieving a SSE from GoLang server, but the Arabic script is not encoded probely:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar-AR">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/gh-pages/qrcode.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="msg"></div>
</body>
<script src="socket.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

And

```
var source = new EventSource("http://localhost:1234/sse/signal");
source.onmessage = function (event) {
    var message = event.data
    document.querySelector('#msg').innerHTML = message;
}
```

And sample output I get is:

```json
data: {
    "IsFromMe": false,
    "IsGroup": false,
    "ID": "26DE3A6A0AEA98406D286E9C58C40114",
    "PushName": "Ø¥Ø¯Ø§Ø±Ø© Ù‚Ø·ÙˆÙ Ùˆ Ø­Ù„Ø§",
    "Timestamp": "2022-07-05T09:45:46+03:00",
}
```

The `PushName` above should be Arabic script!

Comment: What is the `Content-Type` header you are sending from golang?

Comment: Why do you think the problem is on the client side and not on the server side?

Comment: @slebetman the 'Content-Type' is 'text/event-stream'

Comment: @Codo because the server side sending the same as email, and the email is displayed properly

Comment: Then that's probably where your problem comes form. It should be `text/event-stream; charset=utf-8`. See: https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index

Comment: Or if it's not utf-8 it should specify the correct charset

Comment: @slebetman perfectly done, if you post it as an answer will be glad to accept it. thanks a kot

Comment: Does it work? I googled the spec again and the original spec for `EventSource` states `"Event streams are always decoded as UTF-8. There is no way to specify another character encoding."` (see: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html#server-sent-events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @slebetman in his comments, the correct answer is to send the data from the server as `utf-8` which is done in my case as I'm sending data as streaming, by sending the `Content-Type` as `text/event-stream; charset=utf-8`

My code in the GoLang server became:

```golang
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream; charset=utf-8")
```